# customTokenIssuer Extension point on WSO2IS 5.7.0 not working as expected

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have deployed extension bundle in component/lib folder. WSO2IS still uses JWTTokenIssuer to generate the token. I don't see any error in extension bundle.

I have override OauthTokenIssuerImpl lets say customTokenIssuer to obtain custom created tokens. but when i debug the log, It is instantiating both customTokenIssuer and JWTTokenIssuer but framework do not use customTokenIssuer to generate token.

I have updated identity.xml with customTokenIssuer class.

Is it something I am missing in the POM or missing some entries in any of the XML ?

```
[2019-05-23 10:53:59,900]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.config.OAuthServerConfiguration} -  An instance of abc.xxx.xxx.xx.customTokenIssuer is created for Identity OAuth token generation.

..........

[2019-05-23 10:54:00,084] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.util.OAuth2Util} -  Added OAuthTokenReqMessageContext to threadlocal
[2019-05-23 10:54:00,086] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.JWTTokenIssuer} -  JWT Access token builder is initiated
[2019-05-23 10:54:00,086]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.config.OAuthServerConfiguration} -  An instance of org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.JWTTokenIssuer is created for Identity OAuth token generation.

...................

[2019-05-23 10:54:00,092] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.handlers.grant.AbstractAuthorizationGrantHandler} -  OAuth application id: XXxXXXXXXXXXXXXX, user access token validity time 3600000ms
[2019-05-23 10:54:00,092] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.handlers.grant.AbstractAuthorizationGrantHandler} -  OAuth application id : XXxXXXXXXXXXXXXX, access token validity time in milliseconds : 3600000
[2019-05-23 10:54:00,096] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.JWTTokenIssuer} -  Access token request with token request message context. Authorized user XXxXX@carbon.super
[2019-05-23 10:54:00,096] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.JWTTokenIssuer} -  User Access Token Life time set to : 3600000ms.
[2019-05-23 10:54:00,097] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.JWTTokenIssuer} -  JWT Self Signed Access Token Life time set to : 3600000ms.
[2019-05-23 10:54:00,098] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.JWTTokenIssuer} -  Scope exist for the jwt access token with subject XXxXX@carbon.super and the scope is openid
[2019-05-23 10:54:00,154] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.handlers.grant.AbstractAuthorizationGrantHandler} -  Existing access token has expired, but refresh token is still valid for client: XXxXXXXXXXXXXXXX. Remaining time: 17420133ms. Using existing refresh token.
```

As per me only customTokenIssuer should be instantiated and used to generate the token.

Answer (score 1):

Once the custom OAuthTokenGenerator added in the identity.xml file, we need to configure the relevant token Issuer in identity inbound Authentication configurations under service provider configs.

So now we have to go to the **Service provider> Inbound Authentication Configuration > OAuth/OpenID Connect Configuration > Token Issuer and select the Token Issuer configured.**

Without adding that configs in service provider, the changes in the token issuer will not be reflected for the service provider.

Answer (score 0):

Forgot to select token issuer in service provider, Once you deploy the custom token generator jar and update identity.xml file you have to select the Token issuer from the service provider.